What are the pros and cons of the two different declaritive methods in SQLAlchemy 2.0
This page, https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/declarative_tables.html#declarative-table-with-mapped-column, desribes two different ways of using Declarative Mapping
Declarative Table with mapped_column()
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"

    id = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = mapped_column(String(50), nullable=False)
    fullname = mapped_column(String)
    nickname = mapped_column(String(30))

and then the Annotated Declarative Table, which ueses the Mapped object
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(50))
    fullname: Mapped[Optional[str]]
    nickname: Mapped[Optional[str]] = mapped_column(String(30))

The first one seems much more straight-forward.  What are the advantages of the 2nd one?  The type is specified twice, both as a Python type and as an SQLAlchemy type


The second version provides python type annotations so that mypy or other static type checkers (editors, etc.) can provide type checking throughout your python code, ie. you cannot assign a known int to a str like user.fullname = 15.

The second version can infer the database types from the python type annotations which can be simpler and shorter.  Especially if you have to define the python type annotations anyways.


Note that the second version also only repeats the database types if they can't be inferred from the python type, ie. int --> Integer, str --> String,  etc.  In this case the length of the String(30) in the database is set so it cannot be inferred just from the python type str.  Although there is another example in the documentation where you can annotate types to pass this information. mapping-multiple-type-configurations-to-python-types
